# binding paramters in struts2 without the form

Tags: binding, parameters, struts2

HI:
When using a form,the parameter form the clien can be bound to an object,for example:

[processing-forms.html](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.1/docs/processing-forms.html)

In the client:

```
<s:form action="register">

      <s:textfield name="personBean.firstName" label="First name" />
      <s:textfield  name="personBean.lastName" label="Last name" />
      <s:textfield name="personBean.email"  label ="Email"/>  
      <s:textfield name="personBean.age"  label="Age"  />

      <s:submit/>

</s:form>
```

In the severside:

```
public class Register extends ActionSupport {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Person personBean;
        //................
}
```

Then the parameter of the client are bound to the personBean instance.

Now,my problem is how to bind the parameters without a from?

My action work as a service which will be called in the javascript,so how to bind them?

I know how to get the parameters:

```
Map(String,Object) map=ActionContext.getContext.getParameters();
String firstName= map.get("firstname")[0];
```

//..........

This is too ugly :(

---

**`UPDATE`**

```
public class ParaWrapper(){
  private String firstName;
  public void setFirstName(String ..){
    this.firstName=...
  }
  //the getter of firstName
  public ....
}


public MyAction extends ActionSupport{
  private ParaWrapper wrapper;
  public void setXXX()...
  public void getXXX()...
  public void execute(){
    System.out.println(wrapper); //here I can not get the parameters,it seems that the parameters are not poputed to this object.
  }
}
```

Since I do not use the s:form tag,so How do struts know where to put the paramters ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you shouldn't use private fields for the values that should be set via Struts2.

Explanation:

I don't know how you post the parameters to your action via JavaScript, but it should work if you add the necessary parameters to the URL you call. You can possibly call (as suggested in the mailing list):

http://yourdomain/yourstruts.action?personBean.firstName=a_string&personBean.lastName=my_lastName& ... (more person parameters)

Struts2 will understand the dot-notation and try to set the personBean variable in your target action. If this is of a Bean class (with an empty public constructor and public setters for each parameter), it will generate a new object and call the setters with the parameters. If it cannot access the parameters, nothing can be set.

So, if your setters are public and your PersonBean class is defined correctly, a PersonBean should be in your actions personBean field.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks,you are right. But I am a little greedy :) Anyway can avoid the dot in the uri? Since personBean.firstName=a_string&personBean.lastName=my_lastName is long than firstName=a_string&lastName=my_lastName.

Comment: No, the struts2 tags use this terminology specifically for beans. BUT you can of course not use a GET but a POST request with your JavaScript if you know how to do that and put the personBean.firstName=a_string&personBean.lastName=my_lastName ... in the post request so it is not visible in the URL.

Answer (score 3):

You handle it the same way. If your field is named `firstname`, then you will need a `setFirstname` method on the action. Whether the parameters are coming from a form or from JavaScript is irrelevant.

**Update**

Based on your revised code example, you will need a `getWrapper` method on your action to expose the `ParaWrapper` object.

You can avoid the "wrapper." prefix by implementing the `ModelDriven` interface and making `ParaWrapper` your model. Then you would just have parameters such as: firstName, lastName, etc (whatever fields are on `ParaWrapper`).

Comment: Since there are too many parameters,so I have to add all of them as fields in the Action,I wonder if there is anyway to wrap these parameters as one object just like the personBean?

Comment: You sure can. Just create an object to hold all the parameters you need. You'll need getters and setters for all of the fields on the object and you will need a getter for the object itself (on the action).